# Compare column values against another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)

data <- data.frame(
id = 1:500, ht_1 = rnorm(500,10:20), ht_2 = rnorm(500,15:25),
ht_3 = rnorm(500,20:30), ht_4 = rnorm(500,25:35), 
ht_5 = rnorm(500,20:40)
)
```

I would like to identify the values in columns `ht_1:ht_4` that are greater than the values in column `ht_5` (number of observations and means).

For each of these columns, I would then like to replace any values that are greater than `ht_5` with `ht_5`.

Comment: What did you try so far??

Comment: is `data %>% mutate(ht_1  = ifelse(ht_1 > ht_5, ht_1, ht_5))` producing what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the `mutate_at` function like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% as_tibble %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(paste0("ht_", 1:4)), ~if_else(.x > ht_5, ht_5, .x))
```

In this case you can also use `pmin` instead of `if_else` which should be faster.

```
data %>% as_tibble %>% 
      mutate_at(vars(paste0("ht_", 1:4)), ~pmin(.x, ht_5))
```

To see how many values are greater than `ht_5` you can use the `summarise_at`function:

```
data %>% as_tibble %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(paste0("ht_", 1:4)), ~ length(.x[.x > ht_5]))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
   ht_1  ht_2  ht_3  ht_4
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     6    39   131   258
```

Comment: Thanks but i would like to first see how many have values greater than ht_5